# datatypes in macgien learning

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, random-forest, data-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have table with different datatypes. Some of my columns are :

name, time, date, number_of_files, hour_works, type_of_job

Jack, 10:24:54, 2015-02-15, 82, 20, project manager
….etc

I want to train these features to predict type_of_job in the company by using a randomforest model.
My question is should I convert the columns to specific datatypes to get good accuracy and what about time and data? I have around 48970 rows and this is first time I work with machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to convert the data. Usually all the columns should have numeric format:

- you can extract features from time - day, hour, week and so;
- type of job is a categorical feature, common transformation methods are labelencoding and onehotencoding;
- the same could be done with other categorical columns, like name;
- if you use linear model, then numerical features should be normalized;